# Why am I getting this Heroku and Rails error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to deploy my Rails web application on Heroku.
I used scaffold to generate two tables. On my machine it all works perfect using SQLite.

I uploaded my app to heroku and now have a weird problem. When I use:

```
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=development
```

it works with SQL tables. When I change it back to production it shows:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

I typed in the terminal:

```
heroku logs
```

Output:

```
2011-09-07T13:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-07T13:44:31+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16691, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-07T13:44:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-07T13:44:32+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T13:44:32+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=193ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T13:44:47+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-07T13:56:25+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T13:56:25+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=26ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T13:56:25+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.72.50 - - [07/Sep/2011:06:56:25 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T15:00:53+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2011-09-07T15:00:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-07T15:00:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-07T15:00:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-07T15:00:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-07T15:00:55+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-07T15:00:55+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-07T15:00:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 8370 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-07T15:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-07T15:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-07T15:01:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8370, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-07T15:01:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-07T16:07:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2011-09-07T16:07:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-07T16:07:13+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-07T16:07:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited 
2011-09-07T17:10:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2011-09-07T17:10:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to created
2011-09-07T17:10:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-07T17:10:40+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 35396 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-07T17:10:44+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-07T17:10:44+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-07T17:10:44+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:35396, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-07T17:10:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-07T17:10:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T17:10:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=7ms service=173ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T17:10:46+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss, store
2011-09-07T17:10:46+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-09-07T17:54:01+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2011-09-07T17:54:01+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/ dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=5907
2011-09-07T17:54:01+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:10:54:01 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T17:54:02+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/rails.png] miss, store
2011-09-07T17:54:02+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/rails.png dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=6646
2011-09-07T17:54:02+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:10:54:02 -0700] "GET /assets/rails.png HTTP/1.1" 200 6646 "http://falling-winter-505.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T17:54:09+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T17:54:09+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=14ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T17:54:09+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:10:54:09 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T18:01:13+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T18:01:13+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=30ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T18:01:13+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:11:01:13 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T18:03:29+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users] miss
2011-09-07T18:03:29+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T18:03:29+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:11:03:29 -0700] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
2011-09-07T18:03:42+00:00 heroku[api]: Config add RACK_ENV by g...@gmail.com
2011-09-07T18:03:42+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by g...@gmail.com
2011-09-07T18:03:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-09-07T18:03:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2011-09-07T18:03:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-07T18:03:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with S

2011-09-07T18:03:44+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-07T18:03:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-07T18:03:46+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 16194 -e development -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-07T18:03:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-07T18:03:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-07T18:03:49+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:16194, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-07T18:03:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-07T18:03:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2057ms status=200 bytes=1677
2011-09-07T18:03:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=314
2011-09-07T18:03:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/microposts.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-09-07T18:03:52+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/jquery_ujs.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=13425
2011-09-07T18:03:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/jquery.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=26ms status=200 bytes=236203
2011-09-07T18:03:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/users.css dyno=web.1 queue=1 wait=30ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-09-07T18:03:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/scaffolds.css dyno=web.1 queue=2 wait=40ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=1755
2011-09-07T18:03:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/application.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=404
2011-09-07T18:03:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/users.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=4ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=30
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/microposts dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=67ms status=200 bytes=1977
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/application.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=314
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/scaffolds.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=1755
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/users.css dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/microposts.css dyno=web.1 queue=1 wait=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=0
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/microposts.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=30
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/jquery.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=236203
2011-09-07T18:04:08+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/jquery_ujs.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=13425
2011-09-07T18:04:09+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/users.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=30
2011-09-07T18:04:09+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/assets/application.js dyno=web.1 queue=1 wait=4ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=404
2011-09-07T18:04:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Config add RACK_ENV by g...@gmail.com
2011-09-07T18:04:21+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by g...@gmail.com
2011-09-07T18:04:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2011-09-07T18:04:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2011-09-07T18:04:21+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-09-07T18:04:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2011-09-07T18:04:23+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Stopping ...
2011-09-07T18:04:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-09-07T18:04:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `thin -p 30135 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-09-07T18:04:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.2.6 codename Crazy Delicious)
2011-09-07T18:04:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2011-09-07T18:04:28+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:30135, CTRL+C to stop
2011-09-07T18:04:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2011-09-07T18:04:30+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /microposts] miss
2011-09-07T18:04:30+00:00 heroku[router]: GET falling-winter-505.heroku.com/microposts dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=164ms status=500 bytes=728
2011-09-07T18:04:30+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 95.26.190.212 - - [07/Sep/2011:11:04:30 -0700] "GET /microposts HTTP/1.1" 500 728 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2" falling-winter-505.heroku.com
```

My Version of Ruby is 1.9.2p290, and the version of Rails is 3.1.0.

Comment: maybe you forgot to migrate the db on the prod env?

Comment: i printed in terminal `heroku rake db:migrate` and then `heroku db:push`. In production db doesn't work, only in development mode it does.

Comment: so perhaps there's something wrong in your production.rb file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that it works in development mode but not production, I'd say the most likely culprit is your `production.rb` file as John Beynon suggested. The next thing I'd try is to run it in production mode locally. You should get, if nothing else, better error messages.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you did not precompile your assets. Here is how to do it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Answer (score -1):

I know I had lots of troubles with that before. And it was an issue of Heroku not supporting sqlite3 at all. They remove your database.yml file with a new one, which uses mysql. A few things to check:

- Add the mysql or mysql2 gem.
- Does your app depend on data from the database? If so you'll need to find a way to import the new data into mysql as your sqlite databases won't work. I ended up using the yaml_db gem to do this (https://github.com/adamwiggins/yaml_db). And had to do some stuff with

Comment: Heroku uses Postgres (and therefore the 'pg' gem) not Mysql.